# Implement navigation controller's in a view controller

Tags: iphone, ios4, uinavigationcontroller, viewcontroller

I have a view controller and I want to implement a navigation controller inside it, but when I implemented it through Interface Builder or programmatically it doesn't work.

Most of it I implemented through Interface Builder, but here is the code I implemented in the AppDelegate, and which I am trying to implement in my view controller.

```
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
[window addSubview:navController.view];
```

I know I can't implement "window" in a view controller so I tried this in my view controller:

```
[self.view addSubview:navController];
```

But it still doesn't work.

Comment: you need to do it like this [self.window addSubview:navController.view] and before initWithRootViewController you need to alloc your viewController object

Comment: Chk my answer. And do it the same way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the app delegate's applicationDidFinishLaunching you have to add this code.

```
viewController=[[myViewController alloc]init];
navigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController];
[self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];
```

where viewController is the object of the myViewController class to which u need to add the navigation controller. It s declared in the header file of appDelegate.Similarly the navigationController is also declared in tat. Hope this helps.

New code:

```
AppSettings *settings = [[AppSettings alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navCont = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:settings];
navCont.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:navCont animated:YES];
[settings release];
[navCont release];
```

Comment: I have tried implementing this in my appDelegate under applicationDidFinishLaunching but I want to implement it through my own viewController.

Comment: then try replacing the viewcontroller with self and add this code in the loadview method of the the viewcontroller in which u want to implement....

Comment: Like this: -(void)loadView {
    viewController=[[NewAlarm alloc]init];
    navController =[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self];
    [viewController addSubview:navController];
}

Comment: b4 tat i need to kno sometin....u want to move from ur current view to NEwALarm view ? do u have a nav controller in ur current view controller ?

Comment: I have my original view, and from that I launch the NewAlarm view but I don't do that using the navigation controller. I use presentModalViewController instead.

Comment: then where do u want to add this navigation controller ?

Comment: so now u are able to present the modalviewcontroller but unable to add the navigationcontroller to it , right ?

Comment: yeah, I don't know how to add the navigation controller to the NewAlarm view.

Comment: @iphoneFreak let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1891/discussion-between-ravin455-and-iphonefreak)

Comment: I tried your new code using applicationDidFinishLaunching but I always get an error on this line [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:navCont animated:YES];

Comment: I added your code to my viewDidLoad in my current view but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your -applicationDidFinishLaunching:

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
[self.window setRootViewController:navigationController];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```